# Update MediaStore audio tags will not work

Tags: android, mp3, mediastore

I am trying to edit Mp3-Information of the MediaStore.
All the edited Mp3 Songs do not have an album name.

```
ContentResolver res = FindCoverActivity.this.getContentResolver();
Uri sSongUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
Uri uri2 = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sSongUri, song_id);

ContentValues values2 = new ContentValues();
values2.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID,"9999"); //new album_id. I dont know how to get an unused id..
values2.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM, "test_album");
Integer as = res.update(uri2, values2,null,null);
if (as != 0) {
     // got updated
}
```

This code does not work. The result is a messed up mediastore..

Does anyone know more? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is an android table called albums which has the following colmns:

album_id (Integer)

album_key (Text not null)

album (text)

both album_id and album_key are maintained by the android system so do not worry about them.
If I understand your problem, you need to find a specific album and then edit the albumname. You must have these in a specific folder structure otherwise you could not identify an album.
Why not use a pc and some mp3 tagging tool such as Mp3 Tag Tools. This also allows you to add albumart etc.
Hope this helps.